# How to detect empty input value for switch case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to detect when someone does not put anything in the value input and hits submit.  When I set the case to just the two quotations it doesn't work (show's default case: "lol").  If I use two quotations with a space in between then I have to type a space in the input then hit submit in order to see the "Please enter your RSVP code."

```
function myFunction(){

        var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;

        switch (pincode){

            case "77642" :
                window.location.assign("http://wherever.com");
                break;

            case "" :
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please enter your RSVP code.";
                break;

            default :
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "lol";
                break;

            }
        }
```

Seems like a simple thing I'm missing but I haven't been able to find an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just figure out what the value is in this case by outputting it and it's type?

Comment: enter into a switch if you have an input. If no input is given define your action in the else block.

Comment: seems to work fine: [Option empty string value](http://jsfiddle.net/GuLkf/) - [Option no value](http://jsfiddle.net/GuLkf/1/). What does your dom look like?

Comment: That's weird.  It worked when I put that case as the first one but won't work when it's the last one.  Not sure I understand it but it solved the problem.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement before the switch to validate the input:

```
function myFunction(){

    var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;

    if(pincode.trim() == "") { // note the trim for eliminating empty spaces
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please enter your RSVP code.";
        return;
    }

    switch(pincode) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side-note: trim may not be present in all browsers as it is a fairly late addition to Javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). A simply replacement would be `pincode.replace(/^\s*(.*?)\s*/g, '')`.

Comment: @IngoBürk Good to know. I've had zero problems with trim but, if it ever happens, now I know what could be.